# Can one set of data be modelled with an exponential function as well as a power function?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

I have a set of data that contains an ordered pair of (x,y) values.  The data, when plotted, is a curve with one peak, as seen below.  I modelled the tail of the data with a power and exponential function, as seen below.  Both fits were calculated so that the chi squared value is a minimum.  The exponential fit is of the form $y = A_1 e^{B_1x}$, and power fit is of the form $y = A_2x^{B_2}$.
[image: data and fits]

I am confused as to why both models fit the data very well.  The reason for my confusion is that an exponential function is of a very different form than a power function, yet the data is represented by both functions very well.

Edit:  The difference of the exponential fit and power fit looks like the following: [image: difference of fits]

Comment: Could you provide the data points used for the fit used for the tail ?

Comment: I think it would help if you enlarged the tail where they seems to match and also plot the difference of the fits in the tail.

Comment: I have added a graph of the difference of the fits in m question.

Comment: Could you instead provide the last plot for the part of the tail you fitted ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by last plot.  Also, can you please state the reason.

Comment: You wrote : *I modelled the tail of the data with a power and exponential function,* Then, you need to provide the plots only for the range of $x$ you used.